# How can I resolve a "NameResolutionFailure" error when trying to gather data from every type of internet connection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently using `Httpclient` and I can successfully gather my data with a specific network/internet-connection at the place that has the data.

However when I try to gather the data at home with another internet-connection I receive an "NameResolutionFailure" error.

My goal is to be able to reach the data from any type of connection but I am not sure what I am quite missing here. (I am also new in this area).

This is the code that I use when I talk to the db:

```
 string dataurl = "my-url-here";

 var http = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain"),
 };

 var httpClient = new HttpClient(http);

 try
 {
     var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(dataurl);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
 }

 catch (HttpRequestException ex)
 {
     if (ex.GetBaseException() != null)
     {

     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message); //this is where i recieve the NameResolutionFailure error
     }
     else
     {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
  }
```

How come I can only reach the data when I am on a certain network and not with every network? Am I missing code or is there something else in play here?

Appreciate every help, tips, code-examples i can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely to be in the `string dataurl = "my-url-here";` and where that's accessible from.  There are likely to be two obstacles:

- Name resolution
- Network Access

While your error message only mentions Name resolution, I'm guessing you'll need to do something about network access as well.

Name resolution (or DNS) is about translating a host name into an I.P. address.

When you're on a work network, there'll be a name resolution service that resolves local computer names to I.P. addresses on the network.  Normally these local computer names are not visible to public DNS servers.  If you connect your device to a different network (e.g. a mobile network), it uses the public DNS servers, which know nothing about the local domain named computers.

For example `MyServer` might resolve on your local network because it's part of your local domain, and the local network infrastructure will sort that out.    `MyServer.MyCompany.com` is usually similar, as by default machines names aren't exposed externally.

For a mobile application, you're going to need a public domain name. Something like `MyServer.MyDomain.com` (or `www.google.com` is the same thing, essential).  A public DNS server translates this name to an I.P. address.

This is probably where the problem you're experiencing is occurring. You're probably using a local host name, that the public DNS servers don't know about.

If you're working for an organisation they may already have a domain, or you may need to purchase a domain for your application.
In the meantime you could look at one of the dynamic DNS solutions that may allow you to progress for development purposes.

For my Xamarin app, I use the name of the local machine when I'm developing, and the mobile device is on the same network.

If I'm not on the same network, I have a VPN that I can use.  This connects into the work network as if I'm on the same network.  If I'm developing at home and both devices are on my home network, I use the I.P. address of my development box, because I haven't made local DNS work on my home wifi.

When we go to release we use a public URL, like `api.MyApp.com` - which public DNS points to our prod server.

Network Access might be a thing that you need to deal with too.

A major part of a Network Engineer's job is to keep the hackers out.  When your mobile device is on the same network as the server (i.e. when it's working for you), this isn't a problem because because mostly networks are configured so that two devices on the same network can see each other. It sounds like this is the sort of network you have, if your app can see your server on one connection.

But if you're needing to connect to your server from a mobile network, you need a way to tell your network router to forward specific traffic from the internet to your server.
This gets complicated, but for development purposes, strategies I've seen work are:

- A VPN - we have a VPN that I fire up on the mobile device, enter my work network credentials, and then I can access my development box as if I'm on the same network
- Virtual server / port forwarding - if you're at home, you can probably configure your modem to forward a particular port to your development box.  Every modem is different, so you'd have to search up instructions for your particular one.
- Network Engineer - if you're in a corporate, and want traffic from outside to get to a server that you're managing (and don't have a VPN), you probably need to talk to your networks department.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. i have read it but i will need to read it a few more times to understand it completely. when i paste my `dataurl` to a webbrowser it indeed says: "the webpage cannot be reached, it was not possible to find the dns-server to the server...(url)"